# Biology question on hold - can I re-post at another SE (Cognitive Sciences)?

Tags: discussion, support

I have posted a question that is on hold for off-topicness. It has been viewed 70+ times and the answer has also been voted up 3 times just before lock down. So I would really like to see more answers. Removing the post was possible and I'm happy to, but is dissuaded, apparently, as it has received an answer. So is it OK for me to leave the post as is in Biology SE and re-post in Cognitive Sciences? The question is on hold for nearly 4 days and I'm expecting it to be taken down anyway.

Comment: You could add a comment and ask the Mods to do so. Otherwise you will have to ask the question again over at cognitive sciences.

Comment: I have asked the moderators, but it's probably queued in a long list :) I think I will re-post then. Thanks!

Comment: Flag it for migration as well as adding a comment. I think it will have a better chance of being noticed then.

Comment: @Chris, fileunderwater: If either one of you makes the posted comment an answer I'll tick it off as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should flag the question for migration as well as adding a comment. I think it will have a better chance of being noticed by the moderators then. Since there isn't any standard migration paths between beta sites, this has to be handled manually by the moderators.